# Null reference for object class? TrafficService class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I have tried to make the Network Speed in Status bar in android. I have managed to remove the error but app get crashes. I tried to implement it in my sample project.
So far I have reomve the error from TrafficeService class. I want to call it from MainActivity but it showing error in android studio as null refrence.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private boolean isBounded;

    private TrafficService backgroundService;

    private final ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            isBounded = false;
            backgroundService = null;
        }

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            isBounded = true;
            TrafficService.LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (TrafficService.LocalBinder) service;
            backgroundService = mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrafficService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        bindService(serviceIntent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        backgroundService.showNotification();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (isBounded) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            isBounded = false;
        }
    }

}
```

TrafficService.java from the [enter link description here](https://github.com/mridang/gasflow)

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.TrafficStats;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
//import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.text.format.Formatter;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

/**
 * Main service class that monitors the network speed and updates the notification every second
 */
public class TrafficService extends Service {

    /**
     * The constant defining the identifier of the notification that is to be shown
     */
    private static final int ID = 9000;
    /**
     * The identifier if the component that open from the settings activity
     */
    private static final String CMP = "com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity";
    /**
     * The instance of the handler that updates the notification
     */
    private static NotificationHandler hndNotifier;
    /**
     * The instance of the manager of the connectivity services
     */
    private static ConnectivityManager mgrConnectivity;
    /**
     * The instance of the manager of the notification services
     */
    private static NotificationManager mgrNotifications;
    /**
     * The instance of the manager of the wireless services
     */
    private static WifiManager mgrWireless;
    /**
     * The instance of the manager of the telephony services
     */
    private static TelephonyManager mgrTelephony;
    /**
     * The instance of the notification builder to rebuild the notification
     */
    private static NotificationCompat.Builder notBuilder;
    /**
     * The instance of the binder class used by the activity
     */
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    /**
     * The instance of the broadcast receiver to handle intents
     */
    private BroadcastReceiver recScreen;
    /**
     * The instance of the broadcast receiver to handle power saver mode intents
     */
    //private final BroadcastReceiver recSaver = new PowerReceiver();

    /**
     * Initializes the service by getting instances of service managers and mainly setting up the
     * receiver to receive all the necessary intents that this service is supposed to handle.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        Log.i("HardwareService", "Creating the hardware service");
        super.onCreate();
        final SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        Intent ittSettings = new Intent();
        ittSettings.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", CMP));
        PendingIntent pitSettings = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, ittSettings, 0);
        notBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.wkb000);
        notBuilder.setContentIntent(pitSettings);
        notBuilder.setOngoing(true);
        notBuilder.setWhen(0);
        notBuilder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
        notBuilder.setPriority(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        notBuilder.setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE);
        notBuilder.setLocalOnly(true);
        setColor(settings.getInt("color", Color.TRANSPARENT));
        visibilityPublic(settings.getBoolean("lockscreen", true));

        Log.d("HardwareService", "Setting up the service manager and the broadcast receiver");
        mgrConnectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        mgrNotifications = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mgrWireless = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        mgrTelephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        hndNotifier = new NotificationHandler(getApplicationContext());

        if (settings.getBoolean("enabled", true)) {
            Log.d("HardwareService", "Screen on; showing the notification");
            hndNotifier.sendEmptyMessage(1);
        }
        recScreen = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            /**
             * Handles the screen-on and the screen off intents to enable or disable the notification.
             * We don't want to show the notification if the screen is off.
             */
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context ctcContext, Intent ittIntent) {

                if (ittIntent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {

                    Log.d("TrafficService", "Screen off; hiding the notification");
                    hndNotifier.removeMessages(1);
                    mgrNotifications.cancel(ID);
                } else if (ittIntent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {

                    Log.d("TrafficService", "Screen on; showing the notification");
                    connectivityUpdate();
                } else if (ittIntent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED)) {

                    if (ittIntent.getBooleanExtra("state", false)) {

                        Log.d("TrafficService", "Airplane mode; hiding the notification");
                        hndNotifier.removeMessages(1);
                        hndNotifier.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                    } else {

                        Log.d("TrafficService", "Airplane mode; showing the notification");
                        connectivityUpdate();
                    }
                } else {

                    Log.d("TrafficService", "Connectivity change; updating the notification");
                    connectivityUpdate();
                }
            }
        };

        IntentFilter ittScreen = new IntentFilter();
        ittScreen.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        ittScreen.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        ittScreen.addAction(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
        ittScreen.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(recScreen, ittScreen);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            IntentFilter ittSaver = new IntentFilter();
            ittScreen.addAction(PowerManager.ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED);
            //registerReceiver(recSaver, ittSaver);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates the notification with the new connectivity information. This method determines the type
     * of connectivity and updates the notification with the network type and name. If there is no
     * information about the active network, this will suppress the notification.
     */
    private void connectivityUpdate() {

        NetworkInfo nifNetwork = mgrConnectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (nifNetwork != null && nifNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {

            Log.d("TrafficService", "Network connected; showing the notification");
            if (nifNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {

                Log.d("TrafficService", "Connected to a wireless network");
                WifiInfo wifInfo = mgrWireless.getConnectionInfo();
                if (wifInfo != null && !wifInfo.getSSID().trim().isEmpty()) {

                    Log.d("TrafficService", wifInfo.getSSID());
                    notBuilder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.wireless));
                    notBuilder.setContentText(wifInfo.getSSID().replaceAll("^\"|\"$", ""));
                    showNotification();
                } else {

                    Log.d("TrafficService", "Unknown network without SSID");
                    hideNotification();
                }
            } else {

                Log.d("TrafficService", "Connected to a cellular network");
                if (!mgrTelephony.getNetworkOperatorName().trim().isEmpty()) {

                    Log.d("TrafficService", mgrTelephony.getNetworkOperatorName());
                    notBuilder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.cellular));
                    notBuilder.setContentText(mgrTelephony.getNetworkOperatorName());
                    showNotification();
                } else {

                    Log.d("TrafficService", "Unknown network without IMSI");
                    hideNotification();
                }
            }
        } else {

            Log.d("TrafficService", "Network disconnected; hiding the notification");
            hideNotification();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the service is being stopped. It doesn't do much except clear the message queue of
     * the handler, hides the notification and unregisters the receivers.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.d("HardwareService", "Stopping the hardware service");
        unregisterReceiver(recScreen);
        //unregisterReceiver(recSaver);
        hndNotifier.removeMessages(1);
        mgrNotifications.cancel(ID);
    }

    /**
     * Helper method that shows the notification by sending the handler a message and building the
     * notification. This is invoked when the preference is toggled.
     */
    public void showNotification() {

        Log.d("HardwareService", "Showing the notification");
        mgrNotifications.notify(ID, notBuilder.build());
        hndNotifier.removeMessages(1);
        hndNotifier.sendEmptyMessage(1);
    }

    /**
     * Helper method that hides the notification by clearing the handler messages and cancelling the
     * notification. This is invoked when the preference is toggled.
     */
    public void hideNotification() {

        Log.d("HardwareService", "Hiding the notification");
        mgrNotifications.cancel(ID);
        hndNotifier.removeMessages(1);
    }

    /**
     * Helper method that toggles the visibility of the notification on the locksreen depending on the
     * value of the preference in the activity
     *
     * @param visibility A boolean value indicating whether the notification should be visible on the
     *                   lockscreen
     */
    public void visibilityPublic(Boolean visibility) {
        if (visibility) {
            notBuilder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        } else {
            notBuilder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_SECRET);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper method that sets the background color of the notification icon by parsing the RGB value
     * into an int.
     *
     * @param color The internal int representation of the RGB color to set as the background colour
     */
    public void setColor(Integer color) {
        notBuilder.setColor(color);
    }

    /**
     * Binder method to allow the settings activity to bind to the service so the notification can be
     * configured and updated while the activity is being toggles.
     *
     * @see android.app.Service#onBind(android.content.Intent)
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intReason) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    /**
     * The handler class that runs every second to update the notification with the network speed. It
     * also runs every minute to save the amount of data-transferred to the preferences.
     */
    private static class NotificationHandler extends Handler {

        /**
         * The instance of the context of the parent service
         */
        private final Context ctxContext;
        /**
         * The value of the amount of data transferred in the previous invocation of the method
         */
        private long lngPrevious = 0L;

        /**
         * Simple constructor to initialize the initial value of the previous
         */
        @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
        public NotificationHandler(Context ctxContext) {
            this.ctxContext = ctxContext;
        }

        /**
         * Handler method that updates the notification icon with the current speed. It is a very
         * hackish method. We have icons for 1 KB/s to 999 KB/s and 1.0 MB/s to 99.9 MB/s. Every time
         * the method is invoked, we get the amount of data transferred. By subtracting this value with
         * the previous value, we get the delta. Since this method is invoked every second, this delta
         * value indicates the b/s. However, we need to convert this value into KB/s for values under 1
         * MB/s and we need to convert the value to MB/s for values over 1 MB/s. Since all our icon
         * images are numbered sequentially we can assume that the R class generated will contain the
         * integer references of the drawables in the sequential order.
         */
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msgMessage) {

            TrafficService.hndNotifier.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1, 1000L);

            long lngCurrent = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
            int lngSpeed = (int) (lngCurrent - lngPrevious);
            lngPrevious = lngCurrent;

            try {

                if (lngSpeed < 1024) {
                    TrafficService.notBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.wkb000);
                    updateIcon(R.drawable.wkb000);
                } else if (lngSpeed < 1048576L) {

                    TrafficService.notBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.wkb000 + (int) (lngSpeed / 1024L));
                    updateIcon(R.drawable.wkb000 + (int) (lngSpeed / 1024L));
                    if (lngSpeed > 1022976) {
                        TrafficService.notBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.wkb000 + 1000);
                        updateIcon(R.drawable.wkb000 + 1000);
                    }
                } else if (lngSpeed <= 10485760) {
                    TrafficService.notBuilder.setSmallIcon(990 + R.drawable.wkb000
                            + (int) (0.5D + (double) (10F * ((float) lngSpeed / 1048576F))));
                    updateIcon(990 + R.drawable.wkb000
                            + (int) (0.5D + (double) (10F * ((float) lngSpeed / 1048576F))));
                } else if (lngSpeed <= 103809024) {
                    TrafficService.notBuilder.setSmallIcon(1080 + R.drawable.wkb000
                            + (int) (0.5D + (double) ((float) lngSpeed / 1048576F)));
                    updateIcon(1080 + R.drawable.wkb000
                            + (int) (0.5D + (double) ((float) lngSpeed / 1048576F)));
                } else {
                    TrafficService.notBuilder.setSmallIcon(1180 + R.drawable.wkb000);
                    updateIcon(1180 + R.drawable.wkb000);
                }

                Long lngTotal = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                String strTotal = Formatter.formatFileSize(this.ctxContext, lngTotal);
                TrafficService.notBuilder.setContentInfo(strTotal);
                TrafficService.mgrNotifications.notify(ID, TrafficService.notBuilder.build());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("NotificationHandler", "Error creating notification for speed " + lngSpeed);
            }
        }

        private void updateIcon(int value) {
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                return;
            }
            Bitmap bmpIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.ctxContext.getResources(), value);
            TrafficService.notBuilder.setLargeIcon(bmpIcon);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Custom binder class used for allowing the preference activity to bind to this service so that it
     * may be configured on the fly
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {

        public TrafficService getServerInstance() {
            return TrafficService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

errors in IDE

```
2020-02-09 04:48:42.868 12167-12167/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 12167
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.myapplication.TrafficService.showNotification()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.myapplication.TrafficService.showNotification()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```